# How can I simulate an Outgoing call using iOS Callkit

Tags: ios, callkit

I have gone through the iOS [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit) documentation, the below is the code  provided by Apple under the section 'Making Outgoing Calls'. When I try and call the function **startOutGoingCall()** nothing happens i.e. I don't see any outgoing call UI.

Could someone please suggest me how I could trigger a native outgoing call UI.

```
func startOutGoingCall(){
    let uuid = UUID()
    let handle = CXHandle(type: .emailAddress, value: "jappleseed@apple.com")

    let startCallAction = CXStartCallAction(call: uuid)
    startCallAction.destination = handle

    let transaction = CXTransaction(action: startCallAction)
    callController.request(transaction) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error requesting transaction: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Requested transaction successfully")
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Added the delegate method from my code

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXStartCallAction) {
        logMessage(messageText: "provider:performStartCallAction:")

        /*
         * Configure the audio session, but do not start call audio here, since it must be done once
         * the audio session has been activated by the system after having its priority elevated.
         */
        localMedia?.audioController.configureAudioSession(.videoChatSpeaker)

        callKitProvider.reportOutgoingCall(with: action.callUUID, startedConnectingAt: nil)

        performRoomConnect(uuid: action.callUUID, roomName: action.handle.value) { (success) in
            if (success) {
                provider.reportOutgoingCall(with: action.callUUID, connectedAt: Date())
                action.fulfill()
            } else {
                action.fail()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no outgoing UI you get from CallKit. When you make an outgoing call, your app is open, and therefore, it is your app that should show the UI.